# Ajax success responce

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below code which is working fine:

```
success: function (upd_rsp){
  //if email is not register
  if(upd_rsp == "email_no"){
  exstInfo.text("This E-mail is not registered in our Database!");
  exstInfo.addClass("error");
  return false;
  }

  //if email & pass don't match
  if(upd_rsp == "email_pass_no"){
  matchInfo.text("Email and Password don't match!");
  matchInfo.addClass("error");
  return false;
  }
```

Now if I put between those 2 "if" an "else" statement (below), the second "if" does not get executed. Where am I wrong?

```
   else{
   exstInfo.text("");
   exstInfo.removeClass("error");
   return true;
   }
```

Solution works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a `return` value before the second `if` is executed, the script will stop once the `return` is sent.

This is one of the many ways you could do it:

```
success: function (upd_rsp){
  //if email is not register
  var email_error = false;
  var pass_error = false;
  if(upd_rsp == "email_no"){
    exstInfo.text("This E-mail is not registered in our Database!");
    exstInfo.addClass("error");
    email_error = true;
  } else {
    exstInfo.text("");
    exstInfo.removeClass("error");
    email_error = false;
  }


  //if email & pass don't match
  if(upd_rsp == "email_pass_no"){
    matchInfo.text("Email and Password don't match!");
    matchInfo.addClass("error");
    pass_error = true;
  } else {
    ....
    pass_error = false;
  }

  if(email_error == true || pass_error == true){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: yeap... I just noticed it my self.. :) thank you. I just removed the return and is working! But this is happening only with the return true; ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a possible solution. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The reason it is only occuring with the return true is because the ELSE is being executed by the script which is resulting in the return true; being executed. Once something is returned by the script, the script will stop running. In my example above, I've provided a way for you to avoid this issue.

Comment: Tested and working. My solution though is not correct since it showed other conflicts!